# Allowed method / function names in Swift

Tags: ios, function, methods, swift

This is a two-parts question and I couldn't find an answer inside 'The Swift Programming Language' so far.

The first question is:
**What characters are allowed as names of method or functions in Swift?

*Are all unicode characters allowed?***

The second part of the question is:
**Are there some exceptions like reserved names or characters?

*Is there an official list of them somewhere?***

The reason why I'm asking is that I tried to write a function like this and *received an error*:

```
func ?(object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject {
    // some function
    return object
}
```

But when I try using other non-latin characters like ü, ä, ö it works, the following *doesn't throw an error*:

```
func fünctiön(object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject {
    // some function
    return object
}
```

So, this is confusing me.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the reference book:

> Identifiers begin with an uppercase or lowercase letter A through Z,
>   an underscore (_), a noncombining alphanumeric Unicode character in
>   the Basic Multilingual Plane, or a character outside the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane that isn’t in a Private Use Area. After the first
>   character, digits and combining Unicode characters are also allowed.

The **Lexical Structure** section actually lists all the Unicode Ranges allowed for the first character and the other characters.

The reason is obvious - the compiler has to distinguish between identifiers and operators. Allowing punctuation characters in identifiers would make it impossible to differ between an identifier and an operator.

Comment: The following paragraph is also instructive, @Sulthan - consider adding it?

Comment: @Grimxn It is also an interesting paragraph but not the thing the OP is asking.

Comment: doesn't it explain that you could actually use any keyword as an identifier so long as you escape it with back-ticks? That does seem germane to what he's asking...

Comment: @Grimxn It won't allow you to use an interrogation mark as an identifier though :)

Answer (score 1):

As to the second part of your question, the documentation has a list, which is currently:

> The following keywords are reserved and may not be used as
>   identifiers, unless they’re escaped with backticks, as described above
>   in Identifiers.
>
> Keywords used in declarations: class, deinit, enum, extension, func,
>   import, init, let, protocol, static, struct, subscript, typealias, and
>   var.
>
> Keywords used in statements: break, case, continue, default, do,
>   else, fallthrough, if, in, for, return, switch, where, and while.
>
> Keywords used in expressions and types: as, dynamicType, is, new,
>   super, self, Self, Type, _ _ COLUMN _ _, _ _ FILE _ _, _ _ FUNCTION _ _, and
>   _ _ LINE _ _.
>
> Keywords reserved in particular contexts: associativity, didSet, get, infix, inout, left, mutating, none, nonmutating,
>   operator, override, postfix, precedence, prefix, right, set, unowned,
>   unowned(safe), unowned(unsafe), weak and willSet.
>
> Outside the context in which they appear in the grammar, they can be used as identifiers.
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l